# How to resolve this error in Elasticsearch in Linux

Tags: linux, performance, elasticsearch, exception

```
*[2020-01-21 19:26:03.593] [ERROR] fileserver - [RequestID:2032]-Error after returned from scroller 
{ Error: [es_rejected_execution_exception] rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.
TransportService$6@1178a002

org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$6@1178a002 on EsThreadPoolExecutor
[search, queue capacity = 500, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@2b3a276e
[Running, pool size = 7, active threads = 7, queued tasks = 500, completed tasks = 17993798]] 
(and) [es_rejected_execution_exception] 
rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$6@32325cb8
org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$6@32325cb8 on EsThreadPoolExecutor
[search, queue capacity = 500, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@2b3a276e
[Running, pool size = 7, active threads = 7, queued tasks = 500, completed tasks = 17993798]] (and) 
[es_rejected_execution_exception] rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$6@62f726b5 on EsThreadPoolExecutor
[search, queue capacity = 500,*
```

I tried increasing queue size in yml file, but due to that I got an exception in GUI.

Comment: did you get a chance to look at my suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

**Increasing the queue size is just fighting the symptoms and make it worse and would not fix the root cause**, you need to fix the root-cause and for that, you need to understand this exception in detail, [this post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rejected-execution-queue-capacity-1000/89954/2?u=amitmbm) from Elasticsearch developer would help you to understand the cause of the exception.

More quick fix you can do:

1. Use [Task API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html) to figure out the long-running tasks/requests in your cluster and kill them.
2. Most probably some heavy searches are running in your cluster.
3. Add more capacity(CPU, Memory) to your nodes or add more nodes to your cluster.